# C++ function parameter as reference

Tags: c++, qt, reference, coding-style, parentheses

I have a question. Can anyone tell me why someone would declare parameter `r` like that ?

Whats the difference between Record& r and Record(&r) ?

```
QDataStream& operator>>(QDataStream &s, Record(&r))
{
}
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Record(&r)` and `Record &r` are identical type declarations. I don't know why somebody would include the parentheses except for stylistic reasons. Perhaps it's some cruft left over from a refactoring?

Comment: My guess is that the author is having a style war with someone over what the `&` goes with (parameter name or parameter type) and decided to reinforce his view with parens.

Comment: It was just an example from a book. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

As Richard said Record (&r) and Record &r are equivalent. So the important difference is how effectively they communicate the intent of programmer. I personally prefer Record& r over Record &r because I like to separate the type from the name. That said, I would avoid the Record (&r) because it looks so similar to the syntax for function types. For example, Record (&r)() would declare r as a reference to a function such as the following.

```
Record f() { }
```